# MVC Core Create Generic Instance of Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm Converting an existing WebApi project that dynamically instantiates a generic controller.  Basically, if someone GET /Students, I don't create a Student controller, but create a Generic controller of type Students and runtime, using the DefaultHttpControllerSelector:

```
public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
        Type genericControllerType = GetControllerType(domainType);
        return new HttpControllerDescriptor(configuration, controllerName, genericControllerType);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Uri is incorrect");
    }
}
```

I can achieve this in MVC Core doing the following, but since I'm using EntityFramework 6, this isn't going to work because MVC Core must use Dependency Injection to instantiate the DBContext (DbContext keeps throwing Configuration errors because I assume it needs to be scoped, which sucks).

In example:

```
routeBuilder.MapRoute("{controller}", context =>
{
    string controllerType = (string)context.GetRouteValue("controller");
    string method = context.Request.Method;
    ControllerSelector selector = new ControllerSelector();
    Controller controller = selector.SelectController(controllerType);
    MethodInfo info = controller.GetType().GetMethod(method);
    return context.Response.WriteAsync($"Controller {controllerType} was called with method {method}");
});
```

Like I said, it looks like I will need to dynamically create every single generic scope for my types like this example:

```
//Need to loop through all my types that are tied to the generic controller and create these scopes manually I assume
services.AddScoped<SchoolContext>(_ => new SchoolContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

And then have MVC take over the controller creation so that dependency injection works for this DbContext.

Does anyone have any ideas? Maybe I don't need to do this if I can get EF6's DbContext to work, but every time I pass in the ConnectionString name, it throws some kind of dll error (System.Data can't be found/ConfigurationManager can't be found).  I even tried passing in an already established connection to the DbContext.  From reading online, and looking at the samples, it must be passed in the scope like above.

Here's what happens when I try and do the normal DbContext intialization with the connection string name:

[image: Can't find ConfigurationManager]

After adding that reference, I get the following error:

> Could not load type 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

Comment: Is your question about the MVC setup or your problem with EF6? those are distinct problems (EF6 doesn't work on .NET Core)

Comment: @MartinUllrich Ah, you're right.  Looking at the sample project, they're using .net 4.6 even though its an MVC core project.  Super confusing.  Thanks again!